# Android Studio - Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I know this question has been asked several times on the forum but I still haven't succeed in solving the problem.
SO I am trying to use the Parrot's sdk for programming a drone app, on the sdk documentations they say to put this in the gradle
[build.gradle to use Parrot's sdk 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m8OK.png)

Here is one gradle I tried for my the *drone* module of my app:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':referencing')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:v24.2.0'

    compile 'com.parrot:arsdk:3.11.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

and I get this error when making the *drone* module:

```
Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':drone:compileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom
      file:/opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.jar
  Required by:
      DroneRacingApp:drone:unspecified
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom
      file:/opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.jar
  Required by:
      DroneRacingApp:drone:unspecified > com.parrot:arsdk:3.11.0
> Could not find any matches for com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.+ as no versions of com.android.support:support-v4 are available.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
      file:/opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/
  Required by:
      DroneRacingApp:drone:unspecified > com.parrot:arsdk:3.11.0 > com.parrot:libARDiscovery:3.11.0
```

I am new to android and not familiar with all the tools yet. In my project structure the targeted version of the SDL is set to 25 and the minimum to 15.
I have tried to replace the `appcompat` version in *build.gradle* to `25.0.1`, `25.1.1`, `25.0.0`, and other values but it doesn't work.

In the SDK manager the *Android Support Repository* is also installed, I don't have any clue of how I can solve the problem.

Thank you for your help,
regardings.

**Edit:** Here is my project's *build.gradle*, I have not touched it yet.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Edit 2:** Android Studio is looking for `appcompat``in */opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom* whereas the file is located in */opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom*, that may be the real problem.

However, in the project structure window, the android sdk is set to */opt/android-sdk*, but I am not sure if it is part of the android sdk...

So how can I tell android studio to look in the right folder?

Comment: can you show me your project build.gradle?

Comment: Sure, it's added now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the module was a *Java Library* whereas it should be an *Android Library*.
So I've recreated an *Android Library* module and put my classes in it, here is the *build.gradle* in which I have just added the dependency `compile 'com.parrot:arsdk:3.11.0'`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.parrot:arsdk:3.11.0'

}
```

and everything works as expected now!

Comment: You should validate this answer.